# Polymer and AngularJS working together with ng-view

Tags: angularjs, polymer

Recently I have discovered the Polymer Project, which looks really nice and fun to develop with. What I want to do now is combining it with Angular to provide a little routing.
I have an `index.html` page containing all Polymer includes, HTML headers, scripts and styles. Then I want a small piece of code to be on every page of my application, namely the side-menu using `core-drawer-panel`. My approach was to put this part right after the opening `<body>` tag and right below this menu code an `<ng-view></ng-view>` where the specific pages, e.g. `main.html` should be loaded into.
If I put everything, the menu and the page-specific code, into my `main.html`, the routing works fine. But doing it as described above - to have the menu on every page - has the result that only the menu and nothing else is shown up.

Comment: can you share some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Let s see angular material design on github, which is actually an adapted version of the polymer project to Angular :-)

https://material.angularjs.org/#/